# how to send parameters from one module to another module in joomla

Tags: php, mysql, joomla

What I did was I just installed flexi custom code module to use php in my joomla website, I created a new  database rather than the joomla database and I put the code as below it was connected and gave the results.

```
$rows = $result->num_rows;    // Find total rows returned by database
if($rows > 0) {
    $cols = 3;    // Define number of columns
    $counter = 1;     // Counter used to identify if we need to start or end a row
    $nbsp = $cols - ($rows % $cols);    // Calculate the number of blank columns

    $container_class = 'container-fluid';  // Parent container class name
    $row_class = 'row';    // Row class name
    $col_class = 'col-sm-4'; // Column class name

    echo '<div class="'.$container_class.'">';    // Container open
    while ($item = $result->fetch_array()) {
        if(($counter % $cols) == 1) {    // Check if it's new row
            echo '<div class="'.$row_class.'">';    // Start a new row
        }
                     $jid=$item['jid'];
                $jdesc = $item['jdesc'];
                    $duration=$item['duration'];
                     $jobtitle=$item['jobtitle'];

echo ('<div class="'.$col_class.'">'.'<h3>'.'<a href="showjob?jid=' . $jid .    '  ">' .$jobtitle . '</a>' .'</br>'.$jdesc.'<br/>'.$duration.'</h3>'.'<h5>'.$item['name'].'</h5></div>');

if(($counter % $cols) == 0) { // If it's last column in each row then counter remainder will be zero
            echo '</div>';   //  Close the row
        }
        $counter++;    // Increase the counter
    }
    $result->free();
    if($nbsp > 0) { // Adjustment to add unused column in last row if they exist
        for ($i = 0; $i < $nbsp; $i++)  { 
            echo '<div class="'.$col_class.'">&nbsp;</div>';        
        }
        echo '</div>';  // Close the row
    }
    echo '</div>';  // Close the container
}
?>

<?php
$conn->close();
?>
```

It was created database connection and also gave results but with that results I want to send parameters to other module to show the results how can I send the parameters from one module to another,
Finally I want to get the id value into the another module while clicking the link

Comment: Are you talking about module params or are you talking about the result set that you fetched from the database?

Comment: i am talking about jid value fetched from the databse to be passed to another module that is another page showjob page which i was created with menu in joomla

Comment: So, save it in a session / send it via GET or a cookie? not sure I see the issue

Comment: could you send me the code i am new to this

Comment: No, I am not going to write the code for you, if you're new to this then the best way to learn is by doing it yourself. Look into `header(Location:)` and add a GET parameter to it.

Comment: thank you i got solution

Answer (score 0):

I solved this, the problem is that link we are sending to another page  it is saving cache, so i just installed cache manager plugin and added particular page to don't want to save cache.so problem solved, now i can send any parameter to the joomla  module from another module easily.